# Is it possible to create a kotlin multiplatform project referencing the correct target of a common module?

Tags: android, api, kotlin, build.gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

If we would like to build a multiplatform project with Kotlin and we have a structure like this one:

```
common
android
  android1
  android2
backend
  api1
  api2
```

where in the `common` module we have 3 targets / presets:

- `jvm` (with common code to all jvm based projects)
- `jvmAndroid` (with common code to all jvm android projects, depends on jvm)
- `jvmApi` (with common code to all jvm api projects, depends on jvm)

How can we properly configure our `build.gradle`s files to depend only on the correct preset / target?

For example, if we would like to use the common module as a dependency in our other projects we need to use something like:

```
dependencies {
  implementation project(':common')
}
```

But, is it possible to use only the correct part of the common module? Something like this (for android 1 and 2)?

```
dependencies {
  implementation project(':common:jvmAndroid')
}
```

Otherwise when we use `implementation project(':common')` this will get all jvm presets / targets but some code will only make sense or work in the correct platform (in this case android or api).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a strategy called disambiguating targets to achieve this goal.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-set-up-targets.html#distinguish-several-targets-for-one-platform

We need to do something like:

```
val commonAttribute = Attribute.of("com.example", String::class.java)

jvm {
    attributes.attribute(commonAttribute, "nameOfYourTarget")
}
```

Both in the "client" and "server" side. In the same way.