# Is it possible to share a common module between some different platform targets in Kotlin multiplatform?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a project that has an Android client and a backend. They share common code (mainly models for communication). Currently this is implemented using Gradle modules.

Now I want to add a desktop client. This would share some UI code and logic with the Android client. This seems like a use-case for Kotlin Multiplatform. [There is an example of a Backend-client setup with KMP.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-full-stack-app.html#run-the-embedded-server) I imagine I'd have then targets as follows:

- Common // code shared by clients and backend
- jvm("Backend")
- Common-client // code shared by clients
- jvm("Desktop Client")
- Android

But I haven't found a way to define such a `Common-client` target. Is there a way? Is Kotlin Multiplatform the wrong approach for this?

Note: This is different than [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54503916/is-it-possible-to-create-a-kotlin-multiplatform-project-referencing-the-correct), because the common module is not for two targets for the same platform but for different platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Note that "same/different" platforms in this context is defined by the Kotlin, and means, on an intuitive level, "same binary format". Which means that currently, there's only "JVM platform" (doesn't matter, Android, desktop or backend), "JS platform" and "Native platform".

Therefore, the direct answer to your question is to use an answer in the question you've linked, i.e. what is described here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-set-up-targets.html#distinguish-several-targets-for-one-platform

Also, make sure to familiarize yourself with hierarchies: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-hierarchy.html You'll need that in order to create "common-client", i.e. the source set, shared among some, but not all, of the declared targets.

---

That being said, please be aware that this configuration is still not stable (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-28194/Support-of-backend-shared-source-sets-in-Kotlin-Multiplatform), and while it's in general functional, be prepared for some rough edges in the tooling support and unpleasant surprises when working with dependencies.

Note that unless you have a pretty advanced case, you can **happily avoid all those troubles** if you use Gradle Projects instead of Kotlin Source Sets to model the sharing. Because all of your targets are JVM, there's a good chance you'll be able to use just `kotlin("jvm")` in all of them (except Android-client, obviously). And just use the usual dependencies for sharing!

So, for example, `build.gradle.kts` of `desktop-client` will look like that:

```
// desktop-client/build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
}

dependencies {
    api(project(":client-common"))
}
```

And that's how the build.gradle.kts of `client-common` would look like:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
}

dependencies {
    api(project(":common"))
}
```

etc.